# Connection to remote postgresql host running docker refused

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have an instance of postgresql running in a docker container.

I can connect to the database from the host that is running docker by:

```
docker exec -u root -it postgres bash
```

And then accessing the database from there by doing an su to user postgres.

If I use a client from a desktop pc / laptop to try and connect I get a connection refused:

```
psql -h 20.XXX.1XX.1XX -p 5432 -U <user>
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "20.XXX.1XX.1XX" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have edited the pg_hba.conf file in the docker instance and added the following:

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

If I run netstat, again within the container I get:

```
root@ee9dg39913cdc:/# netstat -na | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     52651    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

And when I run it on the machine hosting the docker instance:

```
root@VM01:~# netstat -na | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I do not have ufw running at all, so, no firewall issues. The host is an Azure VM and port 5432 is open to the internet.

postgresql.conf is set as:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Given all of the above, can anyone help me understand why I cannot connect to the postgres instance over the internet using:

```
psql -h 20.XXX.1XX.1XX -p 5432 -U <user>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add "tcpip_socket = true" in the conf?

Comment: How did you determine that 20.XXX.1XX.1XX is the host to use?

Comment: The machine hosting the container is only listening for internal connections (from itself) to 5432.  So there is probably no way for outside connections to reach the container, as the host doesn't let them through.

Comment: 20.XXX.1XX.1XX is the host I ssh to in order to access the docker instance. How can I allow outside connections...? I have no firewall running, the security group port is listening... I'm not sure what I am missing